# resetting Cyberoam cr 15i UTM console Password

Tags: serial, password-reset, utm

i forget my cyberoam cr 15i firewall password and i reset the system. but now i cant login through console also. default password 'admin' is not accepting there. when iam connecting to console following sections are coming

```
Phoenix - AwardBIOS v6.00PG, An Energy Star Ally
   Copyright (C) 1984-2003, Phoenix Technologies, LTD

CR-15I REV.B1 

Main Processor : VIA Eden 500MHz(100x5.0)
Memory Testing :  506816K OK + 16M shared memory

DDR DIMM Speed : 533
DDR DIMM Data Width : 64-Bit, Single Channel
IDE Channel 0 Master : None
IDE Channel 0 Slave  : None
IDE Channel 1 Master : TRANSCEND 20080820
IDE Channel 1 Slave  : None

IDE Channel 2 Master : None
IDE Channel 3 Master : None

IDE Channel 1 no 80 conductor cable installed
Warning! CPU has been changed or CPU Ratio changed fail.
Please re-enter CPU settings in the CMOS setup and remember to save before quit!


Press F1 to continue, DEL to enter SETUP
```

here Del is not working and F1 made it do the following:

```
Cyberoam Version 9.5.8 build 60


Password:
Password incorrect

Password:

Password incorrect

Cyberoam Version 9.5.8 build 60


Password:
Password incorrect

Password:

Password incorrect

Cyberoam Version 9.5.8 build 60


Password:
```

no passwords are accepting

so is there any way to reset CLI password?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably already sorted this, but just incase someone else gets sent here from google:

Connect via serial and hit the "RESET" button at the back.
Keep hitting the Enter key to choose which image to load. Choose '0' for the cyberoam loader.

From here select Troubleshoot > Reset console password, which will set the password back to default (admin/admin)

reboot the device and you will be able to login with this password.

Further info here: http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2157